# How to make the items in a list run forever - python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
my_favourite_fruits = ["apple","orange","pear"]
i = 0
while(True):
  print(my_favourite_fruits[i])
  i = i+1
```

This code currently prints the 3 list items, then crashes because there are no more list items to be printed. How do I get these to be printed over and over, using a while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to count anything manually. Having a number hanging out doesn't necessarily mean anything, so handle the incoming data regardless of size and iterate with a nested loop.

```py
my_favourite_fruits = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]

while True:
    for fruit in my_favourite_fruits:
        print(fruit)
```

Note that the while loop will continue forever since there is no exit condition, so that must be handled separately.

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.cycle` in Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) was made just for cases like this:

```
from itertools import cycle    

my_favourite_fruits = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]
endless_fruits = cycle(my_favourite_fruits)
while(True):
    print(next(endless_fruits))
```

Comment: You posted before me. I will remove my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try module `%`.

If the length of the list is `5`, then when `i` will reach `5` then `i` will reset to `5%5 = 0`

```py
my_favourite_fruits = ["apple","orange","pear"]
i = 0
while(True):
    print(my_favourite_fruits[i])
    i = i+1
    i = i%len(my_favourite_fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo operator % to bound the size of i:

```
my_favourite_fruits = ["apple","orange","pear"]
i = 0
while(True):
  print(my_favourite_fruits[i])
  i = (i + 1) % len(my_favourite_fruits)
```

Or skip counting entirely if you don't need it:

```
my_favourite_fruits = "\n".join(["apple","orange","pear"])
while(True):
    print(my_favourite_fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a condition to start again.

```
my_favourite_fruits = ["apple","orange","pear"]
i = 0
while(True):
  print(my_favourite_fruits[i])
  i = i+1
  if i == 3:
    i = 0
```